A movie about an art or music teacher becoming the Principal?
So there is a teacher, either a music or art teacher, its like the 60's at this point. The teacher has an argument with the Principal and he quits and walks out. 
Then we are fast forwarded about 10 or 20 years and the school has totally changed. Instead of being clean and nice its full of kids fighting and there is graffiti all over the lockers. There is a scene where a girl goes into a bathroom and her clothes get ripped off by some bullies. 
The teacher returns but now he has changed. Instead of looking like a hippie he looks very professional and is much cleaner. He takes over the school and changes it around. Cleans it up, students get good grades now, and everything is good. There is another scene where one kid hates everything and is about to jump off the school roof but the teacher (now the Principal) helps him by almost pushing him off. 
Later the Principal gets arrested and the scene that I never finished was when the students come to bail him out and you see a sky at dusk, a small hill, and an eerie glow growing. A song starts playing and I think it was "lean on me" or something like that. I watched it sometime in 2008 and really want to watch the rest. If this helps, the new principle is black.

Actually, the song you mentioned hearing, Lean on Me, is the same as the title of the film.
From Wikipedia: 

Lean on Me is a 1989 dramatized biographical film written by Michael Schiffer, directed by John G. Avildsen and starring Morgan Freeman. Lean on Me is loosely based on the story of Joe Louis Clark, a real life inner city high school principal in Paterson, New Jersey, whose school is at risk of being taken over by the New Jersey state government unless students improve their test scores.

As you mentioned, the film starts in the 60s:

The film begins in 1967 at Eastside High School where a young Joe Louis "Crazy Joe" Clark (Morgan Freeman) is a Social Studies teacher.

Has a big argument where the teacher is sent to another school:

The other board members are sick of Clark's constant picketing and embarrassing public agitation. The other board members inform Clark that the Paterson Board of Education would give them salary increments if they transfer Clark to an elementary school to keep him out of trouble.

But returns 20 years later to a school with major problems:

20 years later, in 1987 Eastside has deteriorated drastically - especially with drug dealings, gang violence and utter chaos occurring on a regular basis.

The rest lines up really well, too... particularly considering the song is the same as you remember.

Are you sure it's not The Principal (1987)?

Rick Latimer is a teacher who gets a job as the principal of a school
  with a very bad reputation. In fact, his transfer there is a kind of
  punishment because he beat his wife's boyfriend. So, Rick finds
  himself in a school where drugs, knives and guns are very usual things

The principal, himself, is played by a white guy, but his assistant is black.
